# How do I save the names and values of inputs in the page to an object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to save values and names of inputs in the page. I want them to save in an object.
I want to save the names of the inputs as object's key and values as object's values.

How can I do that. Actually I only need to save the inputs names and values to some variable. It can be an array or object. It does not matter.

With this code below, it saves only the last name and value of the inputs. It overwrites. I want them to save seperately.

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
window.addEventListener("load", saveAll);
const inputName = {};
function saveAll(){
    inputs.forEach(function(input){
        inputName.key = input.name;
        inputName.value= input.value;
    });
console.log(inputName);
}
```

Comment: `inputs.forEach(function(input){ inputName[input.name] = input.value; });`
this is what you need.

Comment: This gives a better result. []
blur: "0"
brightness: "100"
contrast: "100"
grayscale: "0"
opacity: "100" But I cant use the values in it. input.blur gives undefines or input["blur"];

Comment: you mean inputName.blur ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you highlighted that you want to save the `array` and then use it some where else.

Then you need to move array inside the `function` `saveAll` and then `return` that from that `function` with all your input data saved in the `inputNames`.

**Live Working Demo:**

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");

window.addEventListener("load", saveAll);

function saveAll() {
  let inputNames = [];
  inputs.forEach(function(input) {
    const inputName = {};
    inputName.key = input.name;
    inputName.value = input.value;
    inputNames.push(inputName);
  });
  return inputNames //return the array
}

console.log(saveAll()[0].key) //blur
console.log(saveAll()) //Array
```

```html
<input type="text" name="blur" value="blur" />
<input type="text" name="bar" value="bar" />
<input type="text" name="blah" value="blah" />
```

Comment: @BirolYılmaz glad to hear that. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) interface to extract the data out of your form and put it in *key-value* pairs inside an iterable object.

It also exposes some methods like [`get()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/get) and [`getAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/getAll) to get individual values from the `FormData` object.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');

const onSubmit = event => {
  const formData = new FormData(event.target);
  
  // Loop through formData.
  for (const [key, value] of formData) {
    console.log('Key:', key, '-', 'Value:', value);
  }
  
  // Get individual value from formData.
  const blur = formData.get('blur');
  console.log('Blur is currently:', blur);
  
  event.preventDefault();
};

form.addEventListener('submit', onSubmit);
```

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<form name="testform">
  <label>Blur
    <input type="range" min="0" max="100" name="blur"/>
  </label>
  <label>Brightness
    <input type="range" min="0" max="100" name="brightness"/>
  </label>
  <label>Contrast
    <input type="range" min="0" max="100" name="contrast"/>
  </label>
  <label>Greyscale
    <input type="range" min="0" max="100" name="greyscale"/>
  </label>
  <label>Opacity
    <input type="range" min="0" max="100" name="opacity"/>
  </label>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line where you assign an object to `inputName` with one where you create an **array**.

Move the line which creates that object so it is **inside** the loop.

At the end of the loop `push` the object into the array.

Comment: But then it creates a unique object for any input. Isn't it?

Comment: @BirolYılmaz — Yes, grouped in an array. You said it was fine to use an array in the question. Possibly you missed something important out of the description of what you were trying to achieve.

Comment: I have got what you mean and done it. Thank you. But now there is another problem which I have asked in comments.